# How to use RegEx to get part of redirect url?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have a column with list redirect URL on Google Custom Search Results. I would like to extract the external domain from that combined URL.

**Example:**

1. `https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=3c360356&q=https://examplesite1.co.uk/aa-vv--cc-dd-gggg-/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjj1cvJ79PuAhXBHc0KHRgvBLsgQIAhAC&usg=AOvVaw2vIHUiy31YKWs5c41Q`
2. `https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=3c360356&q=http://www.exmaplesite2.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/research-paper.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiphLKMi80KHcLUCMAQFjAFegQIARAC&usg=AOvVawkm-bXjmxsPxLQ9w3`
3. `https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=3c360356&q=https://examplesite-3.com/home/en/aaa-bbb/38376&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwixq4K7qttXEKHTOEClsQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2ouHhfNNTPV`

From Above URL's, I would like to extract the external domain name

**Results from above examples:**

1. `www.site2.co.uk`
2. `www.exmaplesite2.co.uk`
3. `examplesite-3.com`

I am able to do this in Google Sheet, but need RedEx so that I can use it in Google Data Studio.

Thanks.

Comment: I am able to get the entire URL of external domains from the following regex 

(?<=\&q=)(.*?)(?=\&)

https://regex101.com/r/0odQR7/1

Now, I am looking forward to how to get the TLD.

Comment: Update: with the following regex I am getting just domain names, but it is both matching www.google.com & www.site2.co.uk, I want only the second group? How can I do that? 

(?<=//)(.*?)(?=/) 

https://regex101.com/r/kbO4Wb/1

Comment: Please, [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66181929/edit) instead of put your attempts in comment.

Comment: That generic reference guide is not really a dupe of this problem that OP is facing in `Google Data Studio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with an additional negative lookbehind:

```sh
(?<=(?<!^https)://)[^/]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD8y2x/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=(?<!^https)://)`: Positive lookbehind to assert that we have `://` before current position. Additionally nested negative lookbehind `(?<!^https)` asserts that we don't have starting `https` before `://` thus skipping matching starting URLs
- `[^/]+: Match 1+ of any character that is not` /`

---

**Update:** As per comments below lookbehind is not supported in `Google Data Studio`, hence we can use this regex:

```sh
.https?://([^/]+)
```

And grab domain name from capture group #1.

`.` placed before `https?:` will ensure that we don't match a URL at the start of a line.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But unfortunately, I realized to make it work in Google Data Studio, it should be RE2. If you can help me with that, that will save my day. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I am not a `Google Data Studio` user. Does it support lookbehind as you have used in your attempts?

Comment: No, it is not supported.

Comment: Hmm but your regex was also using it

Comment: Actually, this the first time I am using regex. I was unaware that Google only supports RE2.

Comment: ok try this regex `.https?://([^/]+)` and grab capture group #1

Comment: Perfect. Thank You soo much. And now when I wanted to get the entire URL, not just TLD, I edit your regex to `.https?://([^&]+)`. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Just combine both regexes:

```
(?:(?<=&q=https://)|(?<=&q=http://))(.*?)(?=/.*?&)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/0odQR7/2)